# Flex play mp3 sound

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml, mxmlc

Inn the below code i have placed my mp3 in the src directory where this mxml file resides.So when the swf is loaded i can see the button i am not able to get the mp3 playing is that something to do do with the path

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.media.*;
        import flash.net.*;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.controls.Button;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.media.Sound;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;



        private function clickhandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var s:Sound = new Sound();
            s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sound.mp3");   
            s.load(req);

        }

        private function onSoundLoaded(event:Event):void
        {
            var localSound:Sound = event.target as Sound;
            localSound.play();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<mx:Button id="play" label="PLAY" click="clickhandler(event)"  />

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sound.mp3");
```

you need to specify the full URL to the sound.mp3. Something like

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://server.name.com/path/to/sound.mp3");
```

If you don't want to compile the path into your application, you can use the [`Application.url`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html#url) property, which gives you the URL from which your application was loaded. If you know where your mp3 lives relative to that, you can modify the path appropriately and load from there.

Comment: how can it be loaded from the emebed tag.i.e, i want to give the path of the mp3 file from the <embed> tag.what are the changes to be made in action script

Comment: Take a look at FlashVars, these allow you to pass arbitrary parameters from the `<embed>` element. See the article: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html